# System use case Vs. Business use case

Tags: analysis

I am completely new in analysis and design.....

please some one tell me :

what is the difference between System use case and Business use case ?

As far as I know, there is only one diagram in UML called use case diagram..
Now, what about them ? Do they have separate diagram?

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case):

> A business use case is described in
>   technology-free terminology which
>   treats the business process as a black
>   box and describes the business process
>   that is used by its business actors
>   (people or systems external to the
>   business) to achieve their goals (...)
>
> A system use case is normally
>   described at the system functionality
>   level (for example, create voucher)
>   and specifies the function or the
>   service that the system provides for
>   the user (...)

So, in short, business use cases are more about what the users expect the system to do, and system use cases are more about what the system actually does.

Comment: Interesting article: https://pjhobday.wordpress.com/2010/05/08/business-and-system-use-cases/ , explains several concerns: A Business Use Case is one in which the design scope is business operations; A System Use Case is one in which the design scope is the computer system to be designed. Business Use Cases form part of the user requirements specification, and define the scope of User Acceptance Testing; System Use Cases should focus on the part of the process to be implemented by the system in question: normally be written at a level of detail equivalent to a detailed functional specification

Answer (score 5):

A business use-case describes the steps in a process that achieve a business goal.

A system use-case describes behavior of a system that automates a business use-case.

Answer (score 4):

Use cases can be divided into two types. It is not necessary, but if someone ask you to do that, it is possible.

System use case represents the use cases which are done by the system(not manually).

For example: In a online  hotel reservation system a user books a room. So the booking is a system use case and the user is a system user.

Business use case represents the use cases which are done manually. It is not necessarily done by the system.

For Example: Manual hotel reservation via telephone call. A user calls the hotel and books a room. Here telephoning is not a system use case, because it is not done by the system. The user is also not a system user, because they do not interact with the system.

Answer (score 2):

Use cases are the values provided to the actors by the systems or organizations under study. 
For organizations, named business use case;
For systems, named system use case.
See the picture below (drawn by myself):
[image: Business use case vs. System use case]

Comment: I found "Use cases are the values provided to the actors by the systems or organizations under study" a bit misleading - perhaps you intended to say something like "Use cases provide value to the actors of the systems or organizations under study"? Also, I think "For organizations, named business use case; For systems, named system use case." should be restated for clarity once it suggests that while business use cases are intended for business, system use cases are intended for systems, which - taken literally - is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Software architecture comprises among others with the business view (description of business processes) and with the system view (description of the system). A business use case is describing the functionality of the business view, and the system use case is describing the functionality of the system view. The business use case has its graphic stereotype in the UML standard.