# What is the purpose of writing System use case?

Tags: uml, analysis

What is the purpose of writing System use case? Suppose I have written a bunch of System use case. Will it be converted to sequence diagram? Please correct me if I am wrong.

NOTE: I have searched in SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906783/system-use-case-vs-business-use-case), but it is not explaining what are the next steps after writing the system use case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of writing system use case is to list its functionality. All future step will formalize the structure and/or the behavior of your system in order to fullfill its usecases no more and no less.
These usecases will not be converted in sequences but they can be described in more details by sequences or activities.

Answer (score 1):

One way of looking it at is that Use Cases describe the systems functional requirements. [Use cases as requirements](http://www.processimpact.com/articles/usecase.html)

They are not directly part of the systems design. Once you have all of these functional requirements you must build up the design. This usually take the form of sequence and activity diagrams that explain the behaviour of the system in fulfilling these use cases and class diagrams and data diagrams to explain the structure.