# when we check the business model check box in use case specification on general tab?

Tags: uml, visual-paradigm

When do we have to check the business model check box in use case specification on general tab? Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the software]

Comment: It's definitely not a UML property, so you'll have to look in the Visual Paradigm docs.

Comment: look at the manual for the software version that comes with the software. If you do not know what the button does, try it in different scenarios and see if you can guess what it does. If you do not already know what it does. Instead of asked `When` to use it,  think you should ask `What` does the button do.

Comment: This post should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906783/system-use-case-vs-business-use-case